# Как время в секундах вывести в формате год день час минута секунда?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как время в секундах вывести в формате год день час минута секунда? А то пока что, час минута секунда.

```
def format_duration(seconds):
    seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600)
    hour = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    min = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вот метод гораздо компактнее:

```
import datetime

def convert_seconds(seconds):
    return f"{seconds//31536000} год {(seconds//86400)%365} день {(seconds//3600)%24} час {(seconds//60)%60} минута {seconds%60} секунда"
```

Произведем тесты на поведение:

```
print(convert_seconds(31536000)) #тест года
print(convert_seconds(86400)) #тест днеё
print(convert_seconds(3600)) #тест часов
print(convert_seconds(60)) #тест минут
print(convert_seconds(1234567890)) #общий тест
```

Вывод:

```
1 год 0 день 0 час 0 минута 0 секунда
0 год 1 день 0 час 0 минута 0 секунда
0 год 0 день 1 час 0 минута 0 секунда
0 год 0 день 0 час 1 минута 0 секунда
39 год 53 день 23 час 31 минута 30 секунда
```

---

Так как задачи в основном стоят гораздо глобальнее, мы можем всё это обернуть в класс и задать методы для вывода в различные системы счисления времени, например вот так:

```
import datetime

class TimeConverter:
    @staticmethod
    def toYear(seconds):
        return seconds // 31536000

    @staticmethod
    def toDayInYear(seconds):
        return (seconds // 86400) % 365

    @staticmethod
    def toHourInDay(seconds):
        return (seconds // 3600) % 24

    @staticmethod
    def toMinuteInHour(seconds):
        return (seconds // 60) % 60

    @staticmethod
    def toSecondInMinute(seconds):
        return seconds % 60

# Пример использования
seconds = 1234567890
# Выводит количество лет
print(TimeConverter.toYear(seconds))    
# Выводит количество дней в контексте одного года
print(TimeConverter.toDayInYear(seconds)) 
# Выводит количество часов в контексте одного дня     
print(TimeConverter.toHourInDay(seconds))    
# Выводит количество минут в контексте одного часа
print(TimeConverter.toMinuteInHour(seconds)) 
# Выводит количество секунд в контексте одной минуты
print(TimeConverter.toSecondInMinute(seconds))
```

Вывод:

```
39
53
23
31
30
```

P.S. данный код не учитывает високосные года

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить вывод количества лет и дней в формате "год день час минута секунда" можно воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
def format_duration(seconds):
    minute = 60
    hour = 60 * minute
    day = 24 * hour
    year = 365 * day

    years = seconds // year
    seconds %= year
    days = seconds // day
    seconds %= day
    hours = seconds // hour
    seconds %= hour
    minutes = seconds // minute
    seconds %= minute

    time_elements = []
    if years > 0:
        time_elements.append('{} year{}'.format(years, 's' if years != 1 else ''))
    if days > 0:
        time_elements.append('{} day{}'.format(days, 's' if days != 1 else ''))
    if hours > 0:
        time_elements.append('{} hour{}'.format(hours, 's' if hours != 1 else ''))
    if minutes > 0:
        time_elements.append('{} minute{}'.format(minutes, 's' if minutes != 1 else ''))
    if seconds > 0:
        time_elements.append('{} second{}'.format(seconds, 's' if seconds != 1 else ''))

    if len(time_elements) == 0:
        return 'just now'

    if len(time_elements) == 1:
        return time_elements[0]

    last_element = time_elements.pop()
    return '{} and {}'.format(', '.join(time_elements), last_element)
```

Comment: Спасибо за все решение.

Comment: вместо `name = seconds // k; seconds %= k` можно использовать `name, seconds = divmod(seconds, k)`. Например `years, seconds = divmod(seconds, year)`

Answer (score 0):

В примере выше был import datetime, которым не воспользовались, способ просто ради разнообразия

```
import datetime

def qwe(s):
    x = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=s)).split(',')
    yield from x[-1].split(':')
    yield from [0, 0] if len(x) == 1 else divmod(int(x[0].split()[0]), 365)


tostr = lambda r: '{3} год {4} день {0} час {1} минута {2} секунда'.format(*r)
print(tostr(qwe(60)))  # 0 год 0 день 0 час 01 минута 00 секунда
print(tostr(qwe(1234567890)))  # 39 год 53 день  23 час 31 минута 30 секунда
```